# How to call jquery validation function on a single field using jquery validation engine plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using [jQuery Validation Engine plugin by Position Absolute](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/), trying to submit a form and am still new to jQuery.

I need to do extra checks before submitting the form (i.e. checking that the username is unique) However the username may be unique but in the same time violates the custom validation set on it, so in this case two messages will appear: "letters only" form validation engine, and "username is available" from my function, which doesn't make sense.

So in short, I want to be sure that a certain field is validated before doing some extra stuff. e.g.

```
if ($(selector).is_valid_using_validation_engine) {
    //do some stuff        
}​
```

Any help?

Comment: "Any help ?" Can be hardly done without any piece of code...

Comment: have you read the docs from the validation plugin in question?

Comment: [This is the documentation for your chosen plugin](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/).

Comment: Loai, actually, the only "famous" Validation plugin is [the one written by Jörn Zaefferer, a member of the jQuery team](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).  Also see http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation